# Document displayed at the top of the Finder window

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, finder

I own a MacBook Air. I've recently been having this problem where I'm not sure what I click, but after viewing a document it will stay at the top of my Finder window. I have no idea how to get rid of it (not trash it, I mean just take it off the window).

Here's a picture of the problem:

[image]

The name of the document that is at the top of my window (obviously) is highlighted. I just want to get rid of that.

Comment: Weird. which version of OSX? What year the Air? Does it only happen on Finder's top bar? Do you suspect any of the installed application you have that might have something to do with it?

Comment: strange, maybe a third party app that you installed recently is causing this?

Comment: Click on it and press CMD+Q to quit it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are dropping documents on the Finder toolbar without realizing it.

A document, a folder, an application, *any* item can be dropped on the toolbar to act as a shortcut, a navigation aid, an alias to a Finder view. Perfect place for a Trash button. Hold down Control and click on the toolbar to see choices about what appears, as well as Customize Toolbar.

To remove an item from the toolbar, press Command while dragging it off. Poof.

Or should I say, Boom.